# "Almost" vs "near to"

Tags: adverbs

Consider the phrase below:

> He produced almost no news reports this week.

And this another one:

> He produced near to no news reports this week.

Do "almost" and "near to" have the same meaning here? Are they both grammatically correct? Is one more formal and/or more idiomatic than the another?

Comment: Seems "near to" is very uncommon in this sense.

Comment: How about: "close to" vs "almost"?  "He's close to figuring things out.": "He's almost figured things out."  Cool, huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rate these as synonyms.

I prefer the first construction; "near" contains an inbuilt context of (theoretically) measurable distance (in space or time) which doesn't gel with the dimensionless quantity of news reports.

If you are looking for a more idiomatic expression, try:

> He produced **next** to no news reports this week.